# CDK Table / Material Table with irregular header: how to get two tier header?

Tags: angular, html-table, angular-material

I'm fairly new to Angular and I was wondering if there is a possibility to use the CDK Table / Material Table to have a multi-tier table with irregular headers similar to what is described here: https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/irregular/

For example, my data consists of 5 columns:

- Name (e. g. "People with brown hair")
- Male (e. g. 1)
- Female (e. g. 2)
- Male (e. g. 3)
- Female (e. g. 4)

Where the header would be:

- Who
- Male
- Female
- Male
- Female

Now here comes the deal, the reason I'm having 2 times male and female is that I'd like to group them in "<18 years old" and ">18 years old". Ideally it would look like the example 1 on the aforementioned site.

If this isn't possible, what would be the best component to implement that or should I just go with ngFor in combination with a plain html table?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an element before table with material classes:

```
<div class="mat-header-row">
  <div class="mat-header-cell"> empty (column 1) </div>
  <div class="mat-header-cell"> columns 2-3 </div>
  <div class="mat-header-cell"> columns 4-5 </div>
</div>

<mat-table>...
```

Comment: Oh yes, that would be another option of course. Do you also have a suggestion how I could make sure that div 2 and 3 always match the position of column 2/3 and 4/5 in the mat-table? I'm not 100% sure how to properly size the table but currently I think i will have each column take equal space.

Comment: In case of equal size, I guess 20% and 40%/40% width would do the trick but how would that work when the column width is variable?

Comment: Cells also have `mat-column-PROPERTY` classes, for example `mat-column-male17` or whatever you named your column. You can use them to control styling of columns.

Comment: Ah nice. I guess my problem is more of a general CSS question. So in the table header I would have mat-column-male17 and mat-column-female17. How would I make sure that my additional header, lets call it mat-header-17, would start at the start of mat-column-male17 and ends at the end of mat-column-female17? Sorry if this is a stupid question but I'm not soooo familiar with CSS and JS. I guess I could try to get the columns via JS, check their width and the position of mat-column-male17 and calculate the width and opsition of the header - or is there a nicer way with pure css?